# save the position of a VStack in a @State private var

Tags: ios, swiftui

Is it possible to get the position of a VStack view saved in a @State private var to be able to reset the VStack to that position after a drag gesture moved it?
I do not have any code for this and all I tried with Geometry reader failed.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, in the end it was solved by Simon NG of AppCoda in Chapter 17
Understanding Gestures of his excellent tutorial Mastering-SwiftUI.
A big thanks to you Simon!

To make the View stay put at the end of a drag use:

```
struct ContentView: View {
// drag gesture,remain at end position
@GestureState private var dragOffset = CGSize.zero
@State private var position = CGSize.zero

var body: some View {
    Image(systemName: "star.circle.fill")
        .font(.system(size: 100))
        .offset(x: position.width + dragOffset.width, y: position.height + dragOffset.height)
        .animation(.easeInOut)
        .foregroundColor(.green)
        .gesture(
            DragGesture()
                .updating($dragOffset, body: { (value, state, transaction) in
                    state = value.translation
                })
                .onEnded({ (value) in
                    self.position.height += value.translation.height
                    self.position.width += value.translation.width
                })
        )
}}
```

and to make it come back to its original location use:

```
struct ContentView4: View {
// drag gesture,return to start position
@GestureState private var dragOffset = CGSize.zero

var body: some View {
    Image(systemName: "star.circle.fill")
        .font(.system(size: 100))
        .offset(x: dragOffset.width, y: dragOffset.height)
        .animation(.easeInOut)
        .foregroundColor(.green)
        .gesture(
            DragGesture()
                .updating($dragOffset, body: { (value, state, transaction) in

                    state = value.translation
                })
        )
}}
```